# How to make transparent the header title of tableview en swift ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I'm actually using a table view for display some datas and I'm overriding `willDisplayHeaderView` to add a Custom style for the header. All is working fine except that I can not change the background color of the title header. Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
{
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let title = UILabel()
    title.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 22)
    title.textColor = UIColor(rgba: "#BA0B23")
    title.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font=title.font
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    header.textLabel?.textColor=title.textColor
    header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    let sepFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: header.frame.size.height-1, width: header.frame.size.width, height: 1)
    let seperatorView = UIView(frame: sepFrame)
    seperatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#BA0B23")
    header.addSubview(seperatorView)
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, some help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In story board you can take a table view  cell, give its custom tableViewCell class and then  customise your cell according to design and then in your view controller you can return that cell like this

```
   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
            let cell:CustomHeaderTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header") as! CustomHeaderTableViewCell
            let title = uniqueOrders.arrOrders[section] as? String
            cell.lblHeaderTitle.text = "Order Id-\(title!)"
            return cell
        }


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return uniqueOrders.arrOrders.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return self.array[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Order Id- \(uniqueOrders.arrOrders[section])"
    }
```

Comment: How do you do here to get a transparent background for the header title of the uitableview ?

Comment: you can do that in story board file....In your header view cell  you can take a label to display header title and set its background colour to colour of your choice.

Comment: To set title in code  you can make outlet of label and set like this -  cell.lblHeaderTitle.text = "Order Id-\(title!)". as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you should focus on using viewForHeaderInSection, rather than willDisplayHeaderView.
Here's what I'd do:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 110;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let title = UILabel()
    title.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 22)
    title.textColor = UIColor(rgba: "#BA0B23")
    title.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    headerView.textLabel?.font = title.font
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerView.textLabel?.textColor = title.textColor
    headerView.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    headerView.addsubView(title)

    return headerView;
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: How you do to get `headerView` ?